# Makefile: how to use a command which randomly generates a file or leaves it unchanged

Tags: random, makefile, target

I have a command which sometimes updates a target file, sometimes it leaves it unchanged, but I cannot tell which one of those will happen. I would like to create a dependency that should run ONLY if the first file is updated. I could not do this. Here is a simple Makefile that reproduces this problem:

```
all: file2.txt

file1.txt:
    @if [ ! -f file1.txt -o $(shell bash -c "expr \$$RANDOM \% 2") = 1 ]; \
    then \
        echo "update" >> file1.txt; \
        echo "file1.txt overwritten"; \
    else \
        echo "file1.txt is unchanged"; \
    fi

.PHONY: file1.txt

file2.txt: file1.txt
    cp file1.txt file2.txt
```

The test in the rule for file1.txt will generate `file1.txt` if it does not exists or if a random number modulo 2 is 1. I would like to see `cp file1.txt file2.txt` executed if and only if `file1.txt` is overwritten.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By adding the `.PHONY` setting you are specifically telling make that no matter what that target is *always* considered out of date, so you're directly contradicting what you want to do.

You can use another method to handle this via a "force target", like this:

```
FORCE: ;
file1.txt: FORCE
         ...
```

and remove the `.PHONY` setting.

Comment: Thanks, this works! I still do not understand why though. And it seems to work if I add `.PHONY: FORCE` as well (in case someone creates a FORCE file).

Comment: If you say `.PHONY: file1.txt`, then that file is always considered out of date so anything that depends on it will be rebuilt.  If you instead have `file1.txt` depend on another file that is always out of date, then `file1.txt` will always be rebuilt... but things that depend on `file1.txt` may or may not be rebuilt depending on whether `file1.txt` is updated or not.